# In MVC I want to return view for 404 url, not redirect! How to do it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, routes, http-status-code-404

Two solutions I can think of are:

1. Somehow dedicate a controller to pick up all 404 requests (don't now how to do it)
2. In Global.asax Application_Error somehow render view through a controller and write result into Response (don't know how to do it).

First option is more preferable for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer (2. solution)! :)

For this you should turn off custom errors in web.config:

`<customErrors mode="Off">`

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        if (ex is HttpException)
        {
            var defaultController = new Controllers.ErrorController();
            defaultController.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(this.Request.RequestContext,
                defaultController
            );
            var res = defaultController.NotFound();
            res.ExecuteResult(defaultController.ControllerContext);
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        }
    }
```